# How to animate UIImageView from Array

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have an array of images that I am trying to animate. The code below only shows one image. Just FYI. Boothanim, photostaken, and _arrSlidshowImg are all NSMutableArrays. I have tried every combination of the code below and the ImageView still only shows the first image when three are taken.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < [photostaken count]; i++)
        {

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i]];
        boothanim =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [boothanim  addObject:img];

        }
        [self.shareModeOverlayView.boothbg setAnimationImages:boothanim] ;
        self.shareModeOverlayView.boothbg.animationDuration = 1;
        self.shareModeOverlayView.boothbg.animationRepeatCount = 0;
        [self.shareModeOverlayView.boothbg startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're `re-initializing` ur `array` every time your `for loop` runs. You should `init` your array before the `for loop`.

```
boothanim =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [photostaken count]; i++)
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[_arrSlidshowImg objectAtIndex:i]];
    [boothanim  addObject:img];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect